# Como contar vogais e consoantes em Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Estou tentando solucionar um desafio de código Ruby em dois códigos, um para contar vogais e outro para contar consoantes, já tentei usando a estrutura `for` e `if` mas não tive sucesso.

Esse é o trecho do código que conta as vogais que não está dando certo:

```
def vowels_count(phrase)
  vogais = ["a","á","ã","e","i","o""u","y"]
  for vogais in phrase
    return phrase.count(vogais)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```rb
def vowels_count(phrase)
  vogais = ["a","á","ã","e","i","o","u","y"]
  phrase.count(vogais.join())
end
```

o `.join()` vai concatenar todos os elementos do array em apenas uma string.

Como você não precisa saber quais vogais e quantas vezes aparecem, pode usar o `.count()` passando todas as vogais de uma vez que dessa forma ele vai buscar cada caracter da string separadamente, e somar tudo que encontrou.